# Laravel Eloquent ManyToMany with Pivot, secondary query with variables in pivot table?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I've been playing with laravel a bit and came across a weird edge case I can't quite figure out

I've got the following table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `community_address` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `address_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `community_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `is_billing` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `is_service` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `is_mailing` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)

CREATE TABLE `communities` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
)

CREATE TABLE `addresses` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `address_1` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL COMMENT 'Street address',
  `address_2` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Street adddress 2 (Company name, Suite, etc)',
  `city` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL COMMENT 'City',
  `state` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL COMMENT 'State / Province',
  `zip` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL COMMENT 'Zip / Postal Code',
  `country_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'Country ID',
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
)
```

Which i've represented with the following Laravel Model for a community

```
class Community extends Model
{
    public function addresses(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(Address::class, 'community_address', 'community_id',  'address_id');
    }
}
```

$community->addresses() does in fact return only addresses for the community, but say I want to filter by address type in my pivot table (billing, mailing, etc)

I can try this:

```
   public function getBillingAddress(){
        return $this->addresses()->wherePivot('is_billing','=', true)->firstOrFail()->get();
    }
```

Which does return results, however it's EVERY row in my pivot table matching my query, not running my query off the existing addresses

So my second idea was to use the 'and' boolean argument like so

```
 public function getBillingAddress(){
        return $this->addresses()->wherePivot('community_id', '=', $this->id, true)->wherePivot('is_billing','=', true)->firstOrFail()->get();
    }
```

Which results in the following SQL which errors out (for obvious reasons), but also doesn't quite look like it's searching for what i'd want, even if it did work?

```
select `addresses`.*, `community_address`.`community_id` as `pivot_community_id`, `community_address`.`address_id` as `pivot_address_id` from `addresses` inner join `community_address` on `addresses`.`id` = `community_address`.`address_id` where `community_address`.`community_id` = 2 1 `community_address`.`community_id` = 2 and `community_address`.`is_billing` = 1 limit 1
```

Which looks to me like the "and" value is not, in fact,  a boolean value, but is printing the value as a string straight to the query.

I tried the obvious, and tried to swap the forth argument with "and" and the following sql was generated, which doesn't fail, but returns all addresses, not just addresses linked to my community

```
select `addresses`.*, `community_address`.`community_id` as `pivot_community_id`, `community_address`.`address_id` as `pivot_address_id` from `addresses` inner join `community_address` on `addresses`.`id` = `community_address`.`address_id` where `community_address`.`community_id` = 2 and `community_address`.`community_id` = 2 and `community_address`.`is_billing` = 1 limit 1)
```

Am I missing something obvious here?

With some tinkering with the result SQL I can get what I want, which is the following raw sql query:

```
select `addresses`.*,
       `community_address`.`community_id` as `pivot_community_id`,
       `community_address`.`address_id`   as `pivot_address_id`
from `addresses`
       inner join `community_address` on `addresses`.`id` = `community_address`.`address_id` and `community_address`.`community_id` = 2 and `community_address`.`is_billing` = 1
limit 1
```

How can I achieve the same SQL being generated for me via eloquent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I misunderstood how `wherePivot()` worked, changing the code to the following worked:

```
   public function getBillingAddress(){
        return $this->addresses()->wherePivot('is_billing', '=', true)->get()->first->all();
    }
```

Where the new code is trying to call the is_billing column of the pivot table to further filter the existing table, the old one was trying to filter it by what it was already filtered by, but since it was an inner join, it was returning all the rows (At least I think?)

Either way, this is solved, hope this helps someone in the future.

Answer (score 1):

I think This will be userfull For you If I come up with an example 
we have **Users** **Role** And **Role_User** Tables
we have connect **Users** To **Role** with belongs To Many And we want use select:

*Users models:*

```
function Roles()
{
 return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role', 'role_user', 'user_id', 'role_id');
}
```

*in Our Controller we can write any select like bellow:*

```
class exampleController extends Controller
{
public function index()
{
User::with(['Roles'=>function($query){$query->where(....)->get();}])->get(); 
}

}
```

you can Use any select on query and return what ever you want..

*just be carefull if you need to use any varible in your select you must use 
bellow format*

```
class exampleController extends Controller
{
public function index()
{
$var =...;
User::with(['Roles'=>function($query) use ($var){$query->where(....,$var)->get();}])->get(); 
}

}
```

i hope this will solve your problem...

Comment: Hi Mohammad, I appreciate your answer, however this is a normal query, I need to be able to query against columns that don't exist in the address object (in this case, your "roles" object, but exist in the pivot table)